How do I provision a TomEE instance using gradle?
I've got a gradle build where I pull an instance of tomcat (e.g.:'org.apache.tomcat:tomcat:10.0.27'), extract it, and copy some of the contents to a deployment directory after a bit of customization.  This works fine, but I need to do the same with TomEE.  However, for some reason, tomee does not include the zip artifact, but only the pom, unlike tomcat.  I'm able to get some of the dependencies, but it is missing those for the different profiles (e.g.: tomee-plus), as well as the main tomee distribution.  Is there some way to get the tomee artifact for a particular profile through a maven repo?  Basically, all I'm looking for is a reliable way to do the equivalent of downloading https://dlcdn.apache.org/tomee/tomee-9.1.3/apache-tomee-9.1.3-plus.zip (from the downloads page) through our usual repo (we have a local nexus server that proxies maven.org).

A colleague of mine found the following: org.apache.tomee:apache-tomee:9.1.3
(Annoyingly, this does not show up in a search on https://search.maven.org/search?q=tomee, but show as the first result does on https://mvnrepository.com/search?q=tomee.  It also does not follow the naming pattern of tomcat).
Using the following gives me a configuration that I can use to extract the zip:
tomeeApp('org.apache.tomee:apache-tomee:9.1.3') {
    artifact {
        classifier = 'plume'
        extension = 'zip'
    }
    transitive = false
}

